# Convert the x509 certPool to pemBytes

Tags: go, ssl, x509

In Go there is a function:

```
func (s *CertPool) AppendCertsFromPEM(pemCerts []byte) (ok bool)
```

but there is no way to do the opposite.

How would I convert the x509.CertPool to PEM bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [struct field containing the `[]*Certificate` is unexported](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/cert_pool.go#L14), and there are no functions that expose them. Likely to protect them from exactly what you are wanting to do. Thus, using the package as-is, there is no way to do this. There are also no `interface`s defined, so you wouldn't be able to provide your own implementation of a `CertPool` with this added functionality either.